# Why can I not set 'margin: 0 auto' via Javascript but can set other CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a flexbox, and a drop-down where the user can choose if they want the items within the flexbox to be left aligned (default - no margin value set) or centred (margin: 0 auto).

Changing the drop-down selection triggers a function which uses the following code to change the margin property of div with ID 'PhotoBox':

```
alignmentChange(alignment) {
  switch(alignment) {
    case "Left": document.getElementById('PhotoBox').style.margin = '';
    case "Centre": document.getElementById('PhotoBox').style.margin = '0 auto';
  }
}
```

I've also tried using .removeProperty instead:

```
alignmentChange(alignment) {
  switch(alignment) {
    case "Left": document.getElementById('PhotoBox').style.removeProperty('margin');
    case "Centre": document.getElementById('PhotoBox').style.margin = '0 auto';
  }
}
```

But neither works - as in, the content does not change alignment on screen. However, I have tested them by popping a test (alert) statement after the margin change, to alert the new margin style of 'PhotoBox' - and the alert does reflect that the margin style has been successfully updated! It's just not reflecting on screen?

However, I've tried a couple of test cases using the 'color' and 'fontFamily' properties, which **do** work, so I know there's nothing wrong with my dropdown or function.

```
alignmentChange(alignment) {
  switch(alignment) {
    case "Left": document.getElementById('PhotoBox').style.color = 'yellow';
    case "Centre": document.getElementById('PhotoBox').style.color = 'blue;
  }
}
```

This one using color works, for example.

And when I manually set the margin property of 'PhotoBox' to '0 auto' within 'PhotoBox.css', that works too, so I know it's not a problem with my layout - setting the margin to '0 auto' within the CSS file itself **does** centre the content.

If it's helpful here is all I've got in the raw CSS doc PhotoBox.css:

```
#PhotoBox{
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Any ideas why my JS function is working when I use test properties like color or font family, but not margin? But margin *is* working if I change it directly in the CSS file?

Comment: For the example where `alignmentChange` changes `color` the color will never be `yellow`, it will only set it to `blue`. So I wouldn’t consider that code to be working. The same problem exists for the other `alignmentChange` functions.

Comment: Please produce a simplified example showing the defect. https://jsfiddle.net/ukg3j6ma/ setting margin works as you can see

Comment: @Sammy does the style get applies to the html element?

Comment: Inspect the element in the Elements panel of your browser's developer tools, and check to see if the `margin` property is set or not. Note that if you are using `display: flex` with a value for `justify-content`, setting the `margin` on children may not matter. As always a [mre] would be helpful. Use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to create a runnable one that allows others to replicate the behavior on-site.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably coming from flex box. Otherwise it would work fine as it does below.

First set felx-grow or flex-shrink to 0(none) if the element is a flex child. Then try your code again. If that doesn't work then use the flex-box properties. If the element PhotoBox is the flex-parent then use the "justify-content: center | start | end" property. Or if it's a flex-child then use "justify-self: center | start | end" property.

```
element.style.justifyContent = "start" or "center"
```

By the why you are selecting the element again and again? Just store it in a variable!

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");

let counter = 0;

box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if(counter++ % 2 == 1)
  box.style.margin = "";
  // you can also use- margin: initial;
  else
  box.style.margin = "0 auto";
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Click me</div>
```